# WDS 2012: UEFI Client Network Boot results in error 0x102

Tags: windows-server-2012, pxe-boot, wds, uefi

I've got a WDS 2012 and a DHCP Server 2012 running on the same subnet, but on different boxes.
I have been deploying Windows 8.1 x64 without any issues to BIOS clients, using DHCP Options 66 and 67.

Now I am trying to deploy Windows 8.1 x64 to HP Computers with UEFI.

In order to be able to boot my UEFI-Client from LAN I changed DHCP Option 67 bootfile name to boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi.

When the UEFI Client tries to boot from LAN, it successfully loads wdsmgfw.efi, but then it keeps on "Contacting Server (IP-Address of WDS)" for some minutes and then stops with this message:

Windows Deployment Services encountered an error:
Error Code: 0x102

I guess I am missing something here, but I don't know what it is.
DHCP Option 60 does not seem to be an option, because dhcp and wds are on dedicated servers.

As soon as I switch back to BIOS and wdsnbp.com everything works again.

Comment: Are you using Cisco switches and if so, is PortFast enabled?

Comment: yes sir, cisco switches and PortFast enabled.

Comment: Where did you get your UEFI media? Can you try using the Windows 8.1 Installation media as the UEFI compatible media? Also, In your WDS server set the default boot option for UEFI clients as the newly imported Windows 8.1 x64 media. (the default boot options are found in the server properties)

Comment: It's a Windows 8.1 Enterprise DVD. My default boot image for uefi is boot.wim, the same as for x64 architecture, as there is only one boot.wim on my dvd - I'm afraid the client does not even reach wds after loading wdsmgfw.efi

Comment: Try a 32 bit boot image. Also try without additional NIC drivers. I've had issues with boot images that are 64bit and or have NIC drivers idk why.

Answer (score 2):

Removed dhcp options 66 and 67 and added ip helper address pointing to wds. additionally had to disable netbios over tcp/ip on the wds server.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 2012r2 SCCM servers, and separate 2012r2 DHCP box. SCCM #2 is the DP and WDS server.  I continued to get error 0x102 when booting EFI pxe but then I removed the  DHCP options 66 and 67 and added ip helper to the DP server to the nexus 6k switch and I was able to EFI boot the servers.