# PXE boot does nothing after NBP download

Tags: dhcp, installation, remote, pxe-boot, wds

When client machine boots it succesfully downloads NBP file, next there is

```
Windows Deployment Services (Server IP: 192.168.240.250)
Contacting server ( 192.168.240.250): /
```

And thats it, after a while I get an error message:

```
Error code: 0x102
```

I'm running WDS on Windows server 2016 with separate DHCP (DHCP server is in diferent subnet but IP helpers should be configured). After some hassle I installed wireshark and this is the dump:

```
8     14.009400 Dell_bf:10:d8   Broadcast   ARP 60  Who has 192.168.240.250? Tell 192.168.240.20
9     14.009431 Microsof_fa:14:29   Dell_bf:10:d8   ARP 42  192.168.240.250 is at 00:15:5d:fa:14:29
10    14.009980 192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 TFTP    105 Read Request, File: boot\x64 \wdsmgfw.efi, Transfer type: octet, tsize=0, blksize=1468, windowsize=4
11    14.012900 192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  TFTP    84  Option Acknowledgement, blksize=1468, windowsize=4, tsize=1322528
12    14.013613 192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 TFTP    72  Error Code, Code: Option negotiation failed, Message: User aborted the transfer
13    14.104438 192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 TFTP    97  Read Request, File: boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi, Transfer type: octet, blksize=1468, windowsize=4
14    14.106343 192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  TFTP    70  Option Acknowledgement, blksize=1468, windowsize=4
15    14.106733 192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 TFTP    60  Acknowledgement, Block: 0
16    14.108523 192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  TFTP    1514    Data Packet, Block: 1
.
.
.
1140    14.225958   192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  TFTP    1514    Data Packet, Block: 900
1141    14.226273   192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 TFTP    60  Acknowledgement, Block: 900
1142    14.226328   192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  TFTP    1374    Data Packet, Block: 901 (last)
1143    14.226685   192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 TFTP    60  Acknowledgement, Block: 901
1144    14.535590   192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 DHCP    348 proxyDHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x40e20100
1145    14.593377   192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  DHCP    391 proxyDHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x40e20100
1146    18.254540   ::  ff02::2 ICMPv6  62  Router Solicitation
1147    18.524080   Microsof_fa:14:29   Dell_bf:10:d8   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.240.20? Tell 192.168.240.250
1148    18.524440   Dell_bf:10:d8   Microsof_fa:14:29   ARP 60  192.168.240.20 is at a4:bb:6d:bf:10:d8
1149    20.067981   fe80::a6bb:6dff:febf:10d8   ff02::1:ffbf:10d8   ICMPv6  86  Multicast Listener Report
1150    20.592955   192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 DHCP    348 proxyDHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x40e20100
1151    20.626924   192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  DHCP    391 proxyDHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x40e20100
```

And then it just continues with

```
1190    63.033869   192.168.240.250 192.168.240.20  DHCP    391 proxyDHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x40e20100
1191    69.058796   192.168.240.20  192.168.240.250 DHCP    348 proxyDHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x40e20100
```

Any help would be greatly appretiated.

*Sorry for spelling errors

Comment: Did you try non-UEFI mode ?

Comment: How would I do that? By changing NPB source file?

Comment: Yes. UEFI and BIOS clients boot different NBPs.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot configure client machine to boot using legacy bios. Its new machine and legacy is unsupported.

Comment: I think this is already answered here.
https://serverfault.com/questions/694480/wds-2012-uefi-client-network-boot-results-in-error-0x102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for anyone interested. It was caused by DHCP snooping enabled on our network. After disabling everything worked.